# Протаскивания ползунка в webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Случай такой: значение `input` задается путем перемещения кастомного ползунка, который может находиться где угодно. Есть ли способ протаскивания этого ползунка на заданное количество пикселей в `webdriver.io`? Из стандартных способов там вроде бы как ничего нет.

Приведу примерную разметку:

```js
const slider = $('.slider');
const input = $('input');
let counts = 0;

slider.draggable({
 axis: "x",
  drag: function() {
    counts++
    $('input').attr('value', counts)
  }
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div aria-disabled="false" class="input-range">
  <div class="slider"></div> <!--Этот ползунок можно двигать-->
  <input type="text" name="scale" value="130">
  <!--Изменения записываются сюда. В оригинале это поле скрыто-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Из стандартных способов там вроде бы как ничего нет.

Есть, touchAction: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/touchAction.html

Даже пример имеется:

```
browser.touchAction([
    { action: 'press', x: 200, y: 200 },
    { action: 'moveTo', x: 200, y: 300 },
    'release'
])
```

Comment: you are hell right...